# Find illustration of titular scene from Asimov's "The Naked Sun"

Tags: isaac-asimov, episode-identification, cover-art

Can anyone help me find an illustration of the titular scene from Asimov's *The Naked Sun* when Elijah reaches out of the roof of the taxi and

> contemplated the naked sun

as Daneel grabs him and pulls him back in.

I have it stuck in my head that this image was the cover of a Spanish translation of the book but can't find any images on Google.

Comment: Is it a clear cut taxi or is it more like a spaceship?  I've found a few pictures that might fit the context but I haven't read the series so I'm not sure.

Comment: @user14111 _El Sol Desnudo_

Comment: @DoctorWho22 if only there was some functionality to post links in comments...

Comment: I'm actually not sure that it was a Spanish translation, but I think it was.  In addition, the quote is in the third-to-last paragraph in the second chapter/section. It isn't really a taxi, but some type of vehicle with a convertible roof that takes Daneel and Baley from where the spaceship lands to where they are staying in Solaria.

Comment: @Gallifreyan None of [these covers](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_seeall_7?rh=k%3Ael+sol+desnudo%2Ci%3Astripbooks&keywords=el+sol+desnudo&ie=UTF8&qid=1487292525) for *El Sol Desnudo* seems to fit the OP's description.

Comment: The closest thing I found was a photo of a person in a spacesuit outside of a vehicle but Draneel isn't on it and the title is not El Sol Desnudo.

Comment: Well thanks for looking doctorwho. I can't find anything for it and I've been looking for a while.

Comment: I googled for `the naked sun asimov daneel illustration` and got [Daneel x Lije slash fan-art](http://orig09.deviantart.net/bd88/f/2013/301/e/d/daneel_olivaw_x_lije_baley_sketch_by_mirage_gaogamon-d6s7ieg.jpg) :(

Comment: @user14111  -  search for `asimov [Spanish word for illustration]` :D